# How to use independent models from Directive

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

hi there i have one radio button directive where i will pass model for the collection which will be set to selected Radio button

```
  var app = ChartsModules.getInstance().getModule("amkaiCharts.directives");
app.directive("radioGroup", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            question:"@",       // question for the directive 
            ngModel: '=',  // Selected Model 
            inputarray:"=",     // List of Array input with name, score properties so that those many buttons are created 
        },
        templateUrl: "components/Directives/RadioGroup/radioGroup.html"
    };
});
```

and html is this radioGroup.html

```
    <div  class="btn-group col-md-10 segmented-label" >
        <label    ng-repeat="list in inputarray"    ng-model="$parent.ngModel"    value ="{{list.score}}" btn-radio="{{list.score}}">{{list.name}}</label>

    </div>
</div>
```

so i am sending my array list as 
name: raj score: 10
name: rani score: 20

so i will get 2 radio buttons with name raj and rani so i want to use a model such that if any one selects raj the model should be selected as 10 and for rani its 20

so the problem is when i am using this directive every thing works fine except 
my selected model value is not changing out side directive it

i used directive in html as

if i want to use the selected modal out side the directive i mean where i am using the directive its not reflecting the change out side 
{{mycontroller.Question1}}
i expect here to see selected thing where as in directive html it is showing

so please help me in getting changed or selected value inside Directive to be used outside my directive 
any help is appreciated

Comment: i used controller to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

i used controller to solve this problem i took one variable in controller and assigned a value to it when user selects some value in directive and there by giving the assigned variable as one more attribute to directive solved the problem